# using git stash to move the changes to a different branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit, git-stash

In git if we are accidentally working on a different branches and we do not wish to commit the untested code, I have seen people using stash to save the uncommitted changes, switch to the correct branch and then apply the stash.

As far as I understand, if we have made some changes which is not committed, we can simply move to the correct branch and commit the code. Why do we even need to stash it since changes that are uncommitted will be visible in all the branches.

I remember seeing in some documentation that git will not allow you to switch between branches if you have any uncommitted changes. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 3):

Yes; there might be other developments on the branch you are working on. Suppose:

```
sha2 <good-branch><bad-branch>
sha1 <master>
```

and you have made developments on *bad-branch*, but you haven't committed them, then you can simply do `git checkout good-branch` and commit, without the need to stash. However, if you are in this (or similar) scenario:

```
sha3 <bad-branch>
sha2 <good-branch>
sha1 <master>
```

Then *good-branch and *bad-branch* are not on the same commit, and you cannot just switch branches. Suppose again you have  made developments on *bad-branch*, but you haven't committed them, then There are several ways to proceed:

- use `git stash` to put your work aside, switch branches and reapply them
- commit your changes on *bad-branch* and use `git cherry-pick` to reapply them on *good-branch* (and remove that commit later on from *bad-branch*
- many more possibilities involving creating temporary branches, `git rebase -i`, ...

Answer (score 1):

You don't *have* to stash your uncommitted changes to tracked files before switching branches. It's more a less a safety measure if the branch you're switching to already has files committed under the same name as your uncommitted changes. If you do not stash your changes, `git checkout` would refuse switching branches in that case unless you specify `-f`. If you stash and pop your changes, you get a chance to merge your uncommitted changes with the already committed ones. So it boils down to your preferred workflow and how sure you are about what's already committed in the other branch.